# how can i hide css synthax error from using nesting with postcss

Tags: css, postcss, stylelint

I'm using postcss since few days,
my vs code is showing me errors because I use nested syntax from postcss plugins.

How can I disable this type of error in vs code.
Is stylelint a good way to fix my problem ?
Thank you for your answers.

here's my stylelint.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    extends: ["stylelint-config-standard"],
    rules: {
      "at-rule-no-unknown": [
        true,
        {
          ignoreAtRules: [
            "tailwind",
            "apply",
            "variants",
            "responsive",
            "screen",
          ],
        },
      ],
      "declaration-block-trailing-semicolon": null,
      "no-descending-specificity": null,
    },
  };
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the errors VS Code is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the [PostCSS VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss). It adds language support for PostCSS, letting you use nested syntax and other features. Don't use `stylelint` for this.